# Animate line point using storyboard in metro app

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-8, microsoft-metro, storyboard

How to set the `Line.Y2` and `Line.X2` property using storyboard in metro application.

I have tried using below

```
Storyboard.SetTargetProperty(animation,"Line.Y2");
```

But this is not working.

Please give me any help.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried:

```
 Storyboard.SetTargetProperty(animation, new PropertyPath(Line.X2Property));
```

Comment: Have you used it on metro app?. I thing "new PropertyPath()" method does not exist in metro app.